# not_analyzed is not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

Mapping:

```
include Tire::Model::Search
mapping do
  indexes :name, :boost => 10
  indexes :account_id
  indexes :company_name
  indexes :email, :index => :not_analyzed
end

def to_indexed_json
  to_json( :only => [:name, :account_id, :email, :company_name], 
         )
end
```

From the above mapping the it can be seen that the email field is set to not_analyzed (no broken tokens). I have an user with email vamsikrishna@gmail.com.

Now when I search for vamsikrishna, the result is showing the user...I guess it is using the default analyzer. why?

But, it should be shown only when the complete email is specified I guess (vamsikrishna@gmail.com). Why is the :not_analyzed not considered in this case? Please help.

**I need only the email field to be set as not_analyzed, other fields should use standard analyzer (which is done by default).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching using the `_all` field. It means that you are using analyzer specified for `_all`, not for `email`. Because of this the analyzer specified for `email` doesn't affect your search.

There are a couple of ways to solve this issue. First, you can modify the analyzer for `_all` field to treat emails differently. For, example you can switch to `uax_url_email` tokenizer that works as `standard` tokenizer, but doesn't split emails into tokens.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test-idx' -d '{
  "settings" : {
    "index": {
      "analysis" :{
        "analyzer": {
          "default": {
            "type" : "custom",
            "tokenizer" : "uax_url_email",
            "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "stop"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

The second way is to exclude `email` field from `_all` and use your query to [search against both fields at the same time](https://gist.github.com/3993902#file_email_search.sh).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. No more questions to ask after seeing this answer. I have already solved it by using the default setting. But, I just want to make sure if there was any better way to set the analyzer for specific fields alone without the fields option in search query. I don't want to make much changes in the search query. That doesn't fit my requirement. @javanna accepting this answer as this gives a more detailed info with an example.

Comment: Using a custom analyzer for email was my suggestion. Why is that a bad approach ? I feel that this answer is almost same as my suggestion

Answer (score 1):

try :analyzer => 'keyword' instead of :index => :not_analyzed

what it does is to tokenize the string and hence it will be searchable only as a whole. 
Dont forget to reindex !

Ref - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/keyword-analyzer.html

And still, if u are getting results by searching for vamsikrishna, check if you have other searchable fields with same value (for eg, name / company)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This can be one option.

Comment: Why would you need to analyze the field if you want to index it as it is? Using `not_analyzed` is the best option, unless you want to apply some token filters, thus you do need to analyze the field and use keyword analyzer.

Comment: @javanna Yeah I understand that. That is the reason I said it can be one option. I'm trying to use the not_analyzed option itself. If that's not possible I would try this alternative. Sure will accept if that works and if not_analyzed doesn't work.

Comment: I guess the :not_analyzed option actually means that the field is indexed for filtering rather than searching. The asssumption here is that not_analyzed would only stop tokenizing the attribute. But again, i guess it will even stop analyzing making it usable only for filters. Might be wrong. But this is what i understood from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you should search for the whole field content in order to have a match on it if the specific field is not analyzed.

There are two options:

- The mapping hasn't been submitted correctly. You can check your current mapping through the [get mapping api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-get-mapping.html): 'localhost:9200/_mapping' will give you the mapping of all your indexes. Not a tire expert, but shouldn't you provide not_analyzed as a string? `'not_analyzed'` instead of `:not_analyzed`?
- If you see that your mapping is there, that means you are searching on some other fields that match. Are you specifying the name of the field in your query?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will check it out. Sorry for the mail with the ASAP request.

Comment: To answer the question in the second point, I'm not specifying the name of field in the query. I'm searching on the _all field. Doesn't not_analyzed work for _all field search.

Comment: Ok, so you might have a match on some other field despite of your mapping,but i'd check first if your mapping is there as I suggested.

Comment: Yeah the mapping is indeed there. But, not when I used :not_analyzed. We need to use 'not_analyzed' (as a string). Thanks for that. I have to use the fields API in this case which doesn't fit my requirement.